Download yaml file using node.js
I am trying to download a yaml file from GitHub repository, however when the file is downloaded it always comes with the header as 'text/html', hence I cannot use this file for further processing. What I need is the yaml in as-is format so I can use it further. I also tried using axios.get(), fetch(yamlUrl), https.get() but still same issue. Could you please guide me if I am missing something here. Below are the code snippets that I tried:
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Endpoint to trigger code generation
app.post('/generate-code', async (req, res) => {
const { yamlUrl } = req.body;

try {
    // Fetch the YAML file from the provided URL
    const response = await fetch(yamlUrl);
    const yamlContent = await response.text();

    // Save the YAML file locally
    const yamlFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'api-definition.yaml');
    fs.writeFileSync(yamlFilePath, yamlContent);

    // Run the OpenAPI Generator CLI command
    const outputDir = path.join(__dirname, 'generated-code');
}

Second approach:
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const url = 'https://github.com/.../Test.yaml';
const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, 'downloaded.yaml');

async function downloadYamlFile(url, outputPath) {
try {
//const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
//const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'stream' });
const response = await axios.get(url, { headers: {'Accept': 'text/yaml',} });
if (response.headers['content-type'] === 'application/x-yaml' || response.headers['content-type'] === 'text/yaml') {
fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, response.data);
console.log('File downloaded and saved as', outputPath);
} else {
console.error('The fetched content is not a YAML file.');
}
} catch (error) {
console.error('Error fetching the file:', error);
}
}

downloadYamlFile(url, outputPath);

3rd approach:
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const url = 'https://github.com/...../Test.yaml'

https.get(url, (response) => {
const filePath = fs.createWriteStream('file.yaml');
response.pipe(filePath);
filePath.on('finish',() => {
filePath.close();
console.log('Download Completed');
});
}).on('error', (error) => {
console.log('Error ', error.message);
});

4th option:
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function downloadYamlFile(fileUrl, outputLocationPath) {
const writer = fs.createWriteStream(outputLocationPath);

return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: fileUrl,
    responseType: 'stream',
}).then(response => {
    response.data.pipe(writer);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        writer.on('finish', resolve);
        writer.on('error', reject);
    })
})
}

const fileUrl = 'https://github.com/bian-official/public/blob/main/release12.0.0/semantic-apis/oas3/yamls/Loan.yaml';
const outputLocationPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'file.yaml');

downloadYamlFile(fileUrl, outputLocationPath).then(() => console.log('Download success')).catch(error => console.error('Error', error));

I also tried setting the headers:
return axios({
method: 'get',
url: fileUrl,
headers: {
'Accept': 'application/x-yaml'
},
responseType: 'stream',
})

Downloaded file shows below content instead of yaml file:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
  lang="en"
  
  data-color-mode="auto" data-light-theme="light" data-dark-theme="dark"
  data-a11y-animated-images="system" data-a11y-link-underlines="true"
  >



  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://github.githubassets.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://github.githubassets.com" crossorigin>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com">



"Downloaded file shows below content instead of yaml file" - Because that's the content at that URL.  When you visit that URL in your browser, or request it in something like Postman, what do you see?  I see an HTML page.  Maybe you're looking for something like this instead, to interact with Git itself to pull a file from a repository?

The url should be https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bian-official/public/main/release12.0.0/semantic-apis/oas3/yamls/Loan.yaml. There is a raw button on every github file page

const axios = require('axios'); const fs = require('fs'); const path = require('path');

const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../Test.yaml'; const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, 'downloaded.yaml');

async function downloadYamlFile(url, outputPath) { try { //const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }); //const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'stream' }); const response = await axios.get(url, { headers: {'Accept': 'text/yaml',} }); if (response.headers['content-type'] === 'application/x-yaml' || response.headers['content-type'] === 'text/yaml') { fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, response.data); console.log('File downloaded and saved as', outputPath); } else { console.error('The fetched content is not a YAML file.'); } } catch (error) { console.error('Error fetching the file:', error); } }

downloadYamlFile(url, outputPath);

